# Get nodes with unique attribute value

Tags: php, xml, xpath, duplicates

I want to clean an XML file, and don't allow nodes to have an attribute with the same value. The XML looks like :

```
<bar>
  <foo id="123" some="attribute"/>
  <foo id="abc" some="other attribute"/>
  <foo id="123" some="different attribute"/>
</bar>
```

and it should look like :

```
<bar>
  <foo id="abc" some="other attribute"/>
  <foo id="123" some="different attribute"/>
</bar>
```

I am using PHP but I don't want to make many loops, so I thought of using an XPath request with the DOMXPath object.
I have found that the Xpath *distinct-values* function could help but as far as I understand, it just works for duplicate nodes, not for nodes duplicate attributes.

Is there a solution in XPath, or even a great algorithm in PHP?

Comment: What's the rule for which `foo` node to keep?  The last one seen?

Comment: @TimCooper yes, but in the worst case I could keep the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following xpath

```
/bar/foo[not(@id = following-sibling::foo/@id)]
```

I didn't test it very much since you provided only few test data but I think it could work.